# Scaling Rotation Shearing Reflection algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing

i use EASYBMP library and i want to know the most effective way to scale , rotate , shear and reflect algorithm. i want the most optimized to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most effective way to scale, rotate, shear and reflect is to use the power of your graphics card - for example through OpenGL.

If you still want to do bitmap pixel operations yourself, typically you do this using linear algebra. This is not super easy to figure out, so I recommend finding some good study material, for example [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201848406).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of telling you how to use EASYBMP (which looks like crap), I'm going to suggest you use [Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php?ImageMagick=9559i14b2tb71okfe2999dshg3) instead. It [supports BMP](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) and has all the methods you ask for [built-in](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image.html#Image%20Manipulation%20Methods).

Comment: i want kind of write it myself and understand how it works . if i just want it to be done i will use any editing software.

Comment: @user: It's good that you're trying to learn, but be aware that code to do this sort of thing well and fast tends to be quite hairy and complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the Wikipedia [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) for the transformation matrices